# How do I move / reach a window that I "left" on a second screen?

Tags: window-management, window-manager

I once tested dual-monitor-support for Elementary and had Chrome maximized on the second screen. Everything worked out alright. I unplugged the second screen, Chrome was already closed - but when I reopened Chrome, it apparently opened up on the second screen.

Is there a nicer way to get the window moved than replugging the monitor and move the window with your mouse?

Disclaimer: My first question. Maybe it's stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the second screen monitor in Display settings when it isn't in use. Any windows will be forced to your only screen, and all new windows will stay on this screen.

You can also try <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to view workspaces. You might be able to grab the window there, too.

Not a bad first question :D

Comment: Wow, lots of useful advice here, thank you! :)