# Windows and panel not going to laptop screen when external monitor is pulled out

Tags: release-freya

I'm facing an issue when I pull out the HDMI cable from my laptop. All the windows, panel at the top and panel at the bottom will not move to the laptop monitor once I pull out the HDMI cable. I have to restart my whole system in order to be able to work on just my laptop monitor.

Are there any fixes I can apply to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like my question on how to reach windows that were [left on a second screen](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-move-reach-a-window-that-i-left-on-a-second-screen), so maybe the same advice can help you:

- Disable the second monitor in the settings, *before* pulling the HDMI-plug. This should force all windows to the first (primary) monitor.
- By using SUPER+DOWN you maybe can view all the remaining workspaces and rearrange your windows, in case you forgot to disable the 2nd monitor as described above

Comment: Thx for your reply! I'll will try this out and see if that works. Nonetheless this is a bug I guess.